# geoJSON file structure

Tags: json, leaflet, geojson

I'm working with geoJSON for the first time.  I'm using it to display points and polygons on my Leafletjs map.

I have the following: 59 map points (roughly), 5 construction sites (polygon), and 32 buildings (polygon) that I need to have in my geoJSON file.

I'm not sure if I need to create multiple JSON files or can they all live in one file.  I need to separate them into 3 groups: map points, construction, and buildings in the single JSON file if that is possible.

I did notice on the documentation (geojson.org) that there is a global type and they use "FeatureCollection".  Can this be called someting else so I can make my three groups?  I also notice the features collection and the type of feature for each item.  Can these be named something as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use other names for "FeatureCollection" or "Feature." The nearest you can come to groups in GeoJSON is to give the features of each group a common "tag". Like

```
"features": [
    {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"group": "group1"}, ...},
    {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"group": "group2"}, ...},
    {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"group": "group3"}, ...}]
```

Then, using Leaflet you can bind features to popups or style them differently depending on their "group" tag/property. See http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson.

Answer (score 2):

As @sgillies said, you cannot change the `type` value in your GeoJSON data to something different from what the spec offers you. Otherwise GeoJSON parsers (like Leaflet) will not be able to understand what your data is.

As for storing your data into a single file or into multiple files is up to you.

Now be noted that whenever you call `L.geoJson(myGeoJSONdata)`, Leaflet will create a single Layer Group, whether `myGeoJSONdata` is a `FeatureCollection`, or an array of `Features`.

Therefore if you want to get 3 different Layer Groups within Leaflet (for example if you want to be able to switch ON/OFF each group separately), the simplest way would be to separate your data into 3 different GeoJSON objects (for example they may be in the same JS file that defines 3 different variables, or in 3 distinct JSON files) and to call `L.geoJson` separately on each group of data.

You have plenty other possibilities depending on your programming skills, like having a property within the GeoJSON data that specifies which group each Feature belongs to (like @sgillies mentions), then [filtering](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-filter) by this property while calling `L.geoJson`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help.  I ended up creating 3 separate JSON files and everything seems to be working.  I'm going to open a new thread for a few other questions.  If you could help with them that would be great.